# vlc command for lossless analog video capture

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player

I want to digitize my VHS tapes using a video capture USB thingy.

I wanted to use ffmpeg but sometimes it freezes recording and I haven't found a solution yet, I cannot rely on this. (See: [ffmpeg video recording freezes after "Invalid data found when processing input"](https://superuser.com/questions/1048637/ffmpeg-video-recording-freezes-after-invalid-data-found-when-processing-input))

So, I am trying to find other ways. I would like to know the VLC command (cvlc, or the options I have to use on vlc gui) to capture lossless analog video, I want something similar to the ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i default -f v4l2 -standard pal -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -qp 0 -preset fast -strict -2 zzz.mp4
```

I don't care about de-interlacing right now, I will re-encode and de-interlace later.
I am using Ubuntu Linux.

In case you can propose other software for the same purpose, or you have a solution for the ffmpeg problem, please do so.

Answer (score 0):

I quit searching for solutions for using ffmpeg or vlc, and I am using mencoder now. This blog helped me to start using mencoder: http://easycap.blogspot.com/p/command-line-tv.html